# Two-point function of a free massless scalar field in Euclidean space-time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

Let $\phi(x)$ be a free massless scalar field on $d$-dimesnional space-time with Euclidean metric. I am interested in the operator formalism, i.e. $\phi(x)$ is an operator satisfying $\Delta \phi=0$ where $\Delta=\sum_{i=1}^d \partial_{i}^2$.

> **I would like to compute the two point function** $$D(x):=\langle 0|\phi(x)\phi(0)|0\rangle$$ (there is no time ordering!).

The following elementary argument below leads to a conclusion which does not sound to me to make sense, namely **it proves that $D(x)$ is a constant function**. **My question is whether this answer is indeed correct.**

Since $\Delta\phi(x)=0$ one has $\Delta D(x)=0$. Moreover $D(x)$ is rotation invariant, i.e. depends on $r$ only. The space of such $SO(d)$-invariant solutions outside of 0 must be a linear combination of the constant function 1 and either $\frac{1}{r^{d-2}}$ when $d>2$ or $\log (r)$ when $d=2$.
Since $\Delta \frac{1}{r^{d-2}}$ is proportional to $\delta(x)$ (similarly in 2d) the only possibility is that $D(x)$ is the constant function. This last conclusion does not sound to make sense.

Remark. If one considers the same question in Minkowski space, say in 4d, the 2-point function is 
$$D(x)=\int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^3}\delta(p^2)\theta(p_0)e^{-ip\cdot x}=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2|\vec p|}e^{-i(|\vec p|t-\vec p\cdot \vec x)}.$$
This function does satisfy $\Box D(x)=0$ and is Lorentz invariant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38900/discussion-on-question-by-mko-two-point-function-of-a-free-massless-scalar-field).

Comment: Crossposted to http://mathoverflow.net/q/237647/13917